# How do I add a class to link with a certain anchor string using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, class, anchor, addition

Currently, I have many links on my website that I would like to turn into buttons.  The anchors of each of these links contain the string, "License This Song".  I'm looking for a piece of code that I can add to my WP functions.php file that will add the class "button" to links containing this anchor.

I'm currently working on a jQuery solution, which I'm also having trouble with.  My current code is as follows:

```
// Add "button" class to links containing anchor text "License This Song"
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a:contains('License This Song')").each(function() {
       jQuery(this).addClass('button');
   });
});
```

If I can get it working in jQuery that would be great, but ideally, I would like to have this take place on the server side.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Jim

Comment: post the php code. and your jQuery code should work.

Comment: itachi, Thanks for your reply!  I actually haven't been able to duplicate this code in PHP.  I'm not as well versed in it.  I was hoping someone would be able to share a php solution for the sample thing.  Also, for some reason, the jQuery code is not working either.  I've linked the the javascript in my header.php file.  Any clue as to why it wouldn't be working?

Comment: gove something to work on. we don't even know how you are buiding the links.... as for jQuery code, i see it as correct one. should work.

Comment: Thanks again!  I actually don't have php code to offer.  I certainly understand if you can't help without an examples.  As for the links, I'm running a Wordpress site (self-hosted) and these particular links have been written directly into the posts.  They are not be generated with a php function.  They are hard coded.

Comment: give an example of the output.

Comment: You can view the page: http://jimkulakowski.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with **jQuery**, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('a').each(function() {
       var $this = jQuery(this);
       if ($this.text().indexOf('License This Song') !== -1) $this.addClass('button');
   });
});
```

Check out this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/OPJEox).

Comment: ianaya89, thanks so much for the help!  I see that your codepen example works, but for some reason, it's not working on my site.  Do think there is a conflict with Wordpress?

Comment: @user2221320 mmm maybe, do you see any error in the console? A fiddle with the code or a link your site could help.

Comment: The address is http://jimkulakowski/wp-content/themes/responsive-child-theme/js/buttonClassToLicenseSongLinks.js

Comment: If the person who vote down this could explain the reason will help a lot but I think that the code is correct and is working as expected.

Comment: Wow!  Of course it's not working.  My address was wrong

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement the same solution in PHP?

Comment: @user2221320 Sorry but I can't help you with PHP.